# Ajax isn't showing any results

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

I have been learning Ajax techniques in javascript from various online tutorials and I ended up with this code

```
function fun1 () 
{
    var a;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
        a = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else 
        a = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    a.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (a.readyState == 4 && a.status == 200) 
        {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = a.responseText;
        }
    }

    a.open("POST", "java4s.txt", true);
    a.send();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 300px; height: 30px;">
    Click on the button below
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="fun1()">
    Change Content
</button>
```

I already added "java4s.txt" with some text but after clicking the button(Change Content) there's no effect on the page.I can't find anything wrong about the script.Just help me if it's problem with caching or something else.
p.s: I am using Firefox browser.

Comment: You seem to be missing the onreadystatechange event handler.

Comment: @adeneo Yes i tried with that too , nothing happened , I am Updating my code, look again
:)

Comment: @Ajaz have you checked your response with webmaster tool in firefox or chrome to see if data has been return or if return a state 500???Check it first of all it could be return 200 without data

Comment: To go along with @makemoney2010 press `F12` and check the `Network` tab in Chrome.

Comment: You're testing this with a web server, something like wamp etc ?

Comment: @adeneo no i am just using my browser.

Comment: @makemoney2010 well readyState seems ok as it's giving me 4.but a.status gives me 0.
:O

Comment: @adeneo do i have to use a server here???

Comment: You can't do ajax from a `file://` protocol, you'll need something like [wamp server](http://www.wampserver.com/) to get it working.

Comment: show us code behind so we better understand what are you doing i suppose that issue is in mimeType and or approach to read returned values.

Comment: Well if my script is right then i would check my hosting apps , thnks Guys !
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajaz, where you do a request and check in webmaster tool you should see something like this:
[image: Generic info on request]

Whene click on each request you should see something like this

[image: Detailed request info]

And then clicking on response tab you should see all data returned into the response as per this final image:

[image]

The format of data in this picture is json.

However you need to pay attention about which type of data you return to setup the correct mimeType of the request.In json you need to return "application/json" in xml case "application/xml" and so on.Check it too.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the script. Using Chrome, open up your (F12) developer tools, you should see the response in the network tab or a console error displayed which will fix the issue. If you're having trouble, provide more information on how and where you are hosting the .txt file.

You can see a near exact copy of your script here: [W3Schools Ajax Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_get)

Comment: well i used network tab in firefox and there is no kind of such request.

Comment: Where and how are you hosting the java4s.txt file? on your localhost? are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: I sorted it out , thnx anyways!
:D

Comment: @Ajaz If you found a solution then please add an answer to your question.

Comment: I'm guessing he wasn't hosting the .txt file within his localhost (or routing to it) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This issue came because the CORS was not enabled for the application. It worked after enabling CORS.